# redirect and download pdf on click of radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Need a suggestion from people more intelligent than me. I have a modal which has 2 things, essentially, 3 radio buttons (Email, PDF, None)and a Yes and NO submit button. 
On press of radio button I flag hidden variables appropriately to know if the user pressed email or pdf in my controller. Than user presses Yes for saving (happy path), and it will call a controller. 
This controller will save the changes and redirect to a different page. Now I wanna add to this controller and make it download a pdf. I am doing this by calling my DownloadPDF action.

```
public ActionResult Main(string id)
//code for doing all the save and other stuff
{
if (viewModel.Email)
{
    SendTestingEmail(viewModel.ConsumerEncryptedID);
}
else if(viewModel.PDF)
{
    DownloadWelcomePDF()
}
return RedirectToAction("ConsumerIndex", "Consumer")
```

}

```
    public ActionResult DownloadWelcomePDF(string id)
{
    var htmlWelcomeEmail = db.getHtmlBody(id.DecryptID());
    var converter = new ConvertToPDF();
    var file = converter.ConvertHTMLStringToPDF(htmlWelcomeEmail.EmailBody);
    var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(file, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = string.Format("Welcome{0}{1}_{2}.pdf", htmlWelcomeEmail.ConsumerFirstName, htmlWelcomeEmail.ConsumerLastName, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) };
    return fileStreamResult;
}
```

Now since this will also return pdf content I cannot do both these 2 things (redirecting to a different page and downloading ) at the same time. 
Is there any suggestion, I have been searching internet for a long time.
It is essentially download and redirect but download needs to happen only on certain condition (press of radio) and the page should always redirect nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can break this into two steps.

First on submit you do a check in javascript to see if the user wants to download the PDF. If he wants, then call the download action and then call the main method from JS.

Or you can render the customerIndex page first and pass a flag (something like downloadPDFForId). Based on this flag in the JS in CustomerIndex you can download the file.

The first approach would be a cleaner one.